# Why Powerpoint 10 is not opening a file from network?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, shared-folders, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I upgraded my power-point from 2007 to 2010 recently. Upgraded version is working fine with all the files inside my laptop. But when I tried to open a file from a shared location it fails with a error message. Can anyone help me to rectify this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Can you access the location? Does it let you browse there manually?

Comment: @EricF I can. And excel file in the same folder is working fine without any problem.

Comment: Does it work if you manually copy the file to your desktop and open it from there? Just trying to determine if its network related or version related more so.

Comment: I tried that. In that case also the file is opening without any problem. @EricF

Comment: No clue then but obviously something is wrong with your network

Comment: @EricF the same document I opened from a different system then it worked fine.

Comment: Maybe try reconfiguring your network on your personal machine as that seems to be the issue?